# Laravel 7.x - relate model on latest result in belongsToMany relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, many-to-many, laravel-7

If I'm completely wrong or you got any better solution for this problem, I'm all ears ;-)

The software I'm working on allows the user to add documents to an order, by default the document's status is "visible". If the user decides to delete a file a second status "removed" is attached, so the user can restore it for 14 days; after that another status is attached ("deleted").

the documents and their respective statuses work fine, I receive multiple statuses - as requested - starting with the newest one. So I thought, it might be convenient to automatically join only those documents with the appropriate status as there is only one but unfortunately Laravel isn't as convinced as I am. Here's my code:

```
class Order extends Model 
{
    public function documents()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\OrderDocument')
                    ->with('status')
                    ->whereHas('status', function($query) {
                        $query->first()->where('document_status_name', 'visible');
                    });
    }
}
```

```
class OrderDocument extends Model
{
    public function order()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Order');
    }

    public function status()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\DocumentStatus', 'order_documents_status', 'order_documents_id', 'status_id')
                    ->withPivot('created_at', 'updated_at', 'user_id')
                    ->withTimestamps()
                    ->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc');
    }
}
```

```
class DocumentStatus extends Model
{
    public function orderDocument()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\OrderDocument', 'order_documents_status', 'status_id', 'order_documents_id')
                    ->withPivot('user_id', 'created_at', 'updated_at')
                    ->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc');
    }
}
```

If I change the order Model using this relation

```
public function documents()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\OrderDocument');
}
```

everythings runs smoothly, I receive my order with its documents and every document can have many statuses ordered by created_at desc, but as soon as I add the whereHas condition, I get the following error:

`SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'order_documents.id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from document_status inner join order_documents_status on document_status.document_status_id = order_documents_status.status_id where order_documents.id = order_documents_status.order_documents_id limit 1)`

Of course order_documents.id can't be found, the table isn't joined but I can't even think of why this table is loaded there in the first place?

Does anyone have any tips on how to query only the latest element of a many-to-many relation? I thought of using a globalScope on OrderDocument because it would be easier to "disable" the restriction in case I really want to get all documents ignoring their status but I couldn't get that to work either, interestingly with the same SQL error.

```
protected static function booted()
{
    static::addGlobalScope('visible', function (\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $builder) {
        $builder->whereHas('status', function($query) {
            $query->first()->where('document_status_name', 'visible');
        });
    });
}
```

many thanks in advance!

Comment: "Of course order_documents.id can't be found, the table isn't joined but I can't even think of why this table is loaded there in the first place?" That is because you are using whereHas on status and your belongsToMany status relation is bad clearly.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for my purposes but I would still be really interested in an answer for my question because for my understanding why shouldn't it be possible to relate to models using a condition ...

For the workaround I don't use the relation Order -> OrderDocument directly but via an accessor in which I return only those documents with the appropriate status.

```
public function getDocumentsDetailAttribute()
{
    $documents = [];
    $this->documents->each(function($document) use (&$documents) {
        if(!in_array($document->status->first()->document_status_name, ['visible'])) {
            return;
        }

        $documents[] = [
            'id' => $document->id,
            'name' => $document->name,
            'link' => route('orderdocument.download', ['orderDocument' => $document->id]),
            'created_at' => $document->created_at,
            'status' => $document->status->first()->document_status_name,
       ];
    });

    return $documents;
}
```

Thanks!